# Facebook PHP SDK refresh loop under different sub directory path

Tags: php, facebook-php-sdk

I have searched everywhere (google indexes parallel universe's results too right?) to problem with Facebook PHP SDK refresh loop.

I have narrowed it down to the following scenarios.

My setup:

1. main site (own cms) - http://localhost/
2. wordpress blog - http://localhost/blog

I have a header that is shared across both #1 and #2 above (on wordpress, i created a theme to include functions and share #1's $db object with wordpress).

So, when i login under #1, sites under #1 paths, like `localhost/?mod=some_module` work fine.

But if i point my browser to #2 (`localhost/blog/`) then i get a refresh loop.

Any idea?

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, actually i kinda do few things wrong in my code. But ultimately, i need to set oauth: true for new JS API and new PHP SDK version 3.1.1.

Full description can be found here:
https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/534/